# How to hide last child control in ItemsControl

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have an ItemsControl that uses an ObservableCollection for its ItemsSource.

The ObservableCollection holds type Students.

The ObservableCollection is built using this method in my ViewModel:

```
private void AddStudentToCollection()
{
  List<ClassMates> classMates = new List<ClassMates>();
  classMates.Add(SelectedClassMate);
  Student = new Student(classMates); // Setting the VM property here
  Id = Student.ID; // Setting the VM property here
  StudentCollection.Add(Student);
 }
}
```

Here are the associated properties in the View Model:

```
private Student student;
public Student Student
{
 get
 {
  return this.student;
 }
 set
 {
  this.student = value;
  OnPropertyChanged("Student");
  }
 }

 private int id;
 public int ID
 {
   get
   {
     return this.id;
   }
   set
   {
    this.id = value;
    OnPropertyChanged("ID");
    }
   }

private ObservableCollection<Student> studentCollection;
public ObservableCollection<Student> StudentCollection
{
 get
 {
  if (studentCollection == null)
    studentCollection = new ObservableCollection<Student>();
  return this.studentCollection;
 }
}
```

This is my Student class:

```
public class Student : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
 public Student(List<ClassMates> ClassMates)
 {
  this.ClassMates = ClassMates;
 }

 public IList<ClassMates> ClassMates { get; set; }

 private int id;
 public int ID
 {
  get
  {
    return this.id;
  }
  set
  {
   this.id = value;
   OnPropertyChanged("ID");
  }
 }
```

So this AddStudentToCollection() method is called each time a user selects a row from a Grid. The Student that will be added is the actual selected row.

The ItemsControl holds Grid controls and the Grid controls will look like this:

[------] 1

[------] 1

[------] 1

The 1's here are the ID property in the View Model.

The Grids will contain some more information but this is the basic layout. The ItemsControl will grow as the ObservableCollection grows.

**What I am trying to accomplish:**

I want to hide the last ID property (the last 1) if the Grid is the last element of the ItemsControl.

So I really want the above example as

[----] 1

[----] 1

[----]

Now, just so I am clear, it makes more sense to have a property in the View Model for my project and not have a separate property in the Student Class.

I am wondering if there's a clean, MVVM way of accomplishing this.
Here is my XAML:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding StudentCollection}">
  <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
   <DataTemplate>
    <Grid>
     <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
     </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
     <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition Height="70"/>
      <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
     </Grid.RowDefinitions>
     <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"
      // This is the text of the Label, where the ID is actually displayed.
      Content="{Binding Path=DataContext.ID, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ItemsControl}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
    </Grid>
   </DataTemplate>
  </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
 </ItemsControl>
```

Comment: So the same ID will be displayed in front of each item ? since the Label  is bond to the ID from the VM, not the one in the Student class !?

Comment: Yeah, that's correct.

Comment: So the Vm's ID has always the count of items in the ObservableCollection, right ?

Comment: It is not a direct property, but it will know, yeah

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to add a property to the `Student` class that returns a `bool`, you could use a multi converter in the view that compares the index of the current item to the total number of items displayed in the `ItemsControl`:

```
class MultiConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        ItemsControl ic = (ItemsControl)values[0];
        object item = values[1];

        return ic.Items.IndexOf(item) == ic.Items.Count - 1 ? Visibility.Collapsed : Visibility.Visible;
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

**XAML:**

```
<ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Grid>
            <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"  Content="{Binding Path=DataContext.ID, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ItemsControl}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
                <Label.Visibility>
                    <MultiBinding>
                        <MultiBinding.Converter>
                            <local:MultiConverter />
                        </MultiBinding.Converter>
                        <Binding Path="." RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType=ItemsControl}" />
                        <Binding Path="." />
                    </MultiBinding>
                </Label.Visibility>
            </Label>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: Hmm I am just getting a blank string with this - where all the ID's are blank.

Comment: What exactly is StudentCollection then? There is a reason why you should always provide a MCVE when asking a question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: It is an ObservableCollection of Students. The ID property in the VM will always be identical and assigned to the Student.ID property. It will always be 1 or 2 or 3 or whatever for each student, but the last one will always be an empty String.

Comment: Well, this certainly works for me. Again, please provide a repo of your issue if you need any further help.

Comment: Works great. I modified it just a little. I pass in just the ItemsSource instead of the whole ItemsControl, and I use the converter parameter to determine which index to hide.